# using WSO2 carbon registry for storing sensitive configuration data

Tags: wso2

I have a third party service that I need to call from my AXIS2 web service that I have deployed into a WSO2 App Server.

I would like to store the username and password for the third party service in the Carbon registry, however, I want to protect the sensitive data (e.g. secretpassword), so it isn't visible in the clear by DBA's who have access to the registry data.

```
    SomeService= new SomeService(
         new URL("https://some-server:9443/service"), "admin", "secretpassword");
```

Ideally, the sensitive data would be encrypted.

**Question:** Does the registry support encrypted data?

A similar question has been asked [here](http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Can-we-add-a-registry-media-type-handler-for-encrypted-content-td13882.html), but I haven't been able to find any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For encrypting certain properties of a resource, you can use the Encryption Handler by adding the following config to registry.xml (as described in [this](http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Supporting-Secure-Valut-for-Configurations-stored-in-Registry-Resources-td70585.html) thread):

```
  <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.EncryptionHandler"> 
    <property name="propertyNames">foo,bar</property> 
    <property name="encryptContent">true</property> 
    <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher"> 
        <property name="mediaType">application/vnd.wso2.foo</property> 
    </filter> 
</handler>
```

To secure the secret information in WSO2 Carbon configuration files you can use secure vault as described [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/WSO2+Carbon+Secure+Vault).